# how to modify json schema ref to support null type?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Now I have a large json schema like

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "A example schema",
    "definitions": {
        "stringArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "default": []
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "time": {"type": "string", "minLength": 5},
        "id": {"type": "integer"},
        "members": {
             "type": "array",
             "items": {
                 "properties": {
                     "id": {"type": "string"},
                     "email": {"type": "string"}
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and a new schema using it

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "A example schema",
    "$ref": "example 1"
}
```

I want to modify the second schema to let some filed support null type.

I am thinking to split the first schema into two parts, one for those don't support null, another for those need to support null. For those need to support null, I need to keep two copy, one support null type, one not, because they are all needed in different case.

I wonder if there's a easier way to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First off, importantly, draft 7 ignores any keywords that are siblings of `$ref`, so you'll want to move that `$ref` into a aggregation keyword (we call them "applicators" in the spec).  Typically `allOf` is used:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "A example schema",
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "example 1" }
  ]
}
```

But for your application, you'll want to use `oneOf` because you want to include another subschema that allows for `null` values *as an option*.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "A example schema",
  "oneOf": [
    { "$ref": "example 1" },
    { "type": "null" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't want this ref support to be null type. What I want is let those filed in ref support null type, for example "time"